# Using "cancel" package in pandoc

Tags: pandoc, cancel

I'm trying to convert a .md file that contains the "\cancel" control sequence, but pandoc throws error due to the package "cancel" not being included.

example:

`file.md`

```
$\cancel{X+2}-\cancel{X+2}=c$
```

`pandoc file.md -o file.pdf` output

```
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.52 \(\cancel
```

Comment: You said, ... since package `cancel` is missing,  `\cancel`  has not been defined.  You must load  that package in the latex template or include it the YALM header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `cancel` package in the preamble, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block for details.

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{cancel}
---

$\cancel{X+2}-\cancel{X+2}=c$
```

Then you can convert and typeset with

```
pandoc -f markdown -t latex -i test.md -o test.pdf
```

[image]